# d3 conditional transition of exit and enter selections

Tags: d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart which has time on the x-axis and a count on the y-axis. I have most of the transitions working but there is a scenario where I'm unsure what to do.

If the new data is part of the `update` selection then I know to grow the bars (as they already exist).

If, if however, the data is part of the `enter` selection then, depending on where the data is entering, there are two possible transitions:

1. If the data is newer than the current "end time" then it should slide in from the right, as per [this well known tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html).
2. If the data is new but older than the current "end time" then a new category should be formed.

The analogous situation occurs in the `exit` selection.

I am already taking care of #2 above but am having trouble implementing #1. Especially at the same time as #2. It seem to me that I need to inspect the new datum and see where it falls on the chart, probably using the xScale.

How does one run different transitions on the same selection (enter or exit, in this case)?

Here's some pseudo code for what I could imagine for the exit selection:

```
rects.exit(function () {
    if (d.timestamp < that.chartStartTime) {
       transitionOffLeftEdge();
    } else {
       transitionOffBottom();
    }
)};
```

Comment: I don't see the different scenarios make it more difficult to be honest. Think about it without transitions -- you just compute the final position for everything. To make it a transition, you need a previous position. For the bars that are there, it's clear. For the bars that are new, you could initialise them at their x positions but with no height for example.

Comment: Yes but if the bar is new _and_ it's the most recent, then it should slide in from the right. If it's new but _not_ the most recent, then it should grow from the bottom.

Comment: Ok, so you would need a condition when setting the intial x attribute to check whether it's the most recent. If so, initialise to something outside the canvas.

Comment: It seems like I'll also need a condition to see if the final position should horizontal (look at the endpoints the final example in the [tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html)) or vertical (for those within the chart's endpoints).

Either way, can you point me to any examples of conditional transitions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by horizontal or vertical position.

Comment: In the [tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html), the bars move horizontally - they slide either on (for entering) or off (for exiting) the chart. I'd like to have both horizontal transitions for the edges of the chart as well as vertical transitions for entering/exiting elements _within_ the edges of the chart. By vertical, I simply mean the the bars will shrink to y = 0 or grow to y = d.value.

Comment: That would be the same for all incoming/outgoing bars though, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but all incoming/outgoing bars could be in two different transitioning states: edge bars should transition horizontally and non-edge bars should transition vertically.

Comment: So you don't want the bars that move in or out to grow/shrink? You should be able to check that with a similar condition as above.

Comment: That's right. I don't want the bars that move in/out to grow/shrink.. I've updated the question with some pseudocode.